# Using grep to find a string

Tags: find, grep

I am trying to locate a file that (should) contains the string "1896.345", somewhere under /home/dir/.

Any ideas of how I can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd home/dir

grep -r -l -i "1896\.345" .
```

Comment: A dot instead of the asterisk would avoid any accidental shell expansion.

Comment: I have added an escape backslash to your answer, since otherwise strings like "1896-345" would also be matched.

Comment: This will print the actual match, what the OP asks for is the name of the file, so `grep -rl` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find /home/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 1896.345
```

Comment: I assumed the question meant searching for text within the file, in which case you can use "find /home/dir -type f -exec grep 1896.345 {} \;" - but be warned that this may take a lot of time if there are many files, and will only work if the text is in a plain text file (not eg, LibreOffice document).

Comment: You're right, I misread. Should work now.

Comment: Yeah, but why spawn a separate grep instance for every file that you want to search, when grep -r does the job? That solution makes sense only if you want to limit your search by some other limits (like file creation date, file type, permissions etc.)

Comment: xargs passes as many files as fit into MAXARG to grep. But you're about it being redundant when `grep -r pattern .` will do.